# Element acts like it's always valid(:valid)

Tags: html, css, input, label

why does my input always remain valid even though nothing is being typed? Here’s the code

https://codepen.io/VeljkoCukic/pen/eYZYNqL?editors=1100

```
    #inp:focus + #labela #sp,
#inp:valid + #labela #sp{
  transform:translateY(-150%);
  font-size:14px;
  color: blue; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meanwhile, I found out what's wrong.
**The input element has to have "required" attribute** so it won't be always valid

```
<input type="text" id="inp" required />
```